# Can't set the ItemsSource of comboBox when creating the form via reflection?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have this code that opens a usercontrl in new tab, when a row in the grid is double-clicked, I extract some information from it, and pass an object to the form's constructor:

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var log = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as HistoryLog;
    if (log.JSONClassName != null && log.FormName != null)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ClsUserTransactions oUserTrans = new ClsUserTransactions())
            {
                string jsonLog = oUserTrans.GetJsonLog(log.Id);

                Type jsonType = Type.GetType(log.JSONClassName);
                var obj = Auditor.DeserializeObject(jsonLog, jsonType);
                var formType = Type.GetType("DiERP." + log.FormName);
                var oMainWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
                var frm = Activator.CreateInstance(formType, obj);
                oMainWindow.AddToTab(frm, log.ObjectName);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here's a constructor of a form that has the issue:

```
public FrmArea(JClsTbArea log)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    spanMain.DataContext = log;
    cmbCountry.ItemsSource = log.CmbCountry; //List<TbCountry>
    cmbCountry.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

but the `cmbCountry` is always empty!

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="cmbCountry" 
    Grid.Row="3" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
    Margin="5" 
    SelectedValuePath="CountryId" 
    Validation.Error="Validation_Error"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CountryId, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
    >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountryAName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Is the constructor being called? Is `obj` null?

Comment: of course it's invoked, all the fields are initialized except the combobox

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line that assigns `cmbCountry.ItemsSource = log.CmbCountry` can you see the correct values in log.CmbCountry and see the assignment picking up the new value?

Comment: Yes, I didn't miss that, the ItemsSource goes from count=0 to count = 1

Comment: Maybe something changes it after? Do you have more of code behind like `cmbCountry.ItemsSource = ...` or some triggers in the view? I'd suggest you to create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you remove all irrelevant parts one by one and provide us a full code to see.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint in that empty catch block?